# Syntax Error in Ruby. unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-inputs

Tags: ruby

I'm learning about Modules in Ruby.

The module code was fine, but when I split it and made a file
it returned a syntax error:

```
C:/Desktop/Ruby/Function/5.rb:1:in `require_relative': C:/Desktop/Ruby/Function/Auth.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    from C:/Desktop/Ruby/Function/5.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

This is Auth.rb:

```
module Auth
  module_function()

  def login(id)
    members = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

    for member in members do
      if (id == member)
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

This is 5.rb:

```
require_relative 'Auth'

puts "Input your ID"

input_id = gets.chomp()

if Auth.login(input_id)
  puts "Hello, " + input_id
else
  puts "Who are you?"
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I got example from website and separately try to make a module file and test the module.

Comment: I don't exactly the module_function(), but the person who made this example told that this function makes initialize module variables. Without this function, it occurred the error like "undefined login() function"

Comment: And I removed the parenthesis at the module name. Before it was "Auth()" but it was mistake.

Comment: @Makoto If called with no arguments, module_function causes all subsequently defined methods in the module to become callable as module functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a module using `module Auth()`:

```
irb(main):001:0> module Auth()
irb(main):002:1> end
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
```

and

```
irb(main):001:0> module Auth()
irb(main):002:1>   def login(id)
irb(main):003:2>   end
irb(main):004:1> end
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
(irb):4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Removing the trailing parenthesis fixes the error:

```
irb(main):001:0> module Auth
irb(main):002:1>   def login(id)
irb(main):003:2>   end
irb(main):004:1> end
=> :login
```

and

```
irb(main):001:0> module Auth
irb(main):002:1>   module_function()
irb(main):003:1>
irb(main):004:1*   def login(id)
irb(main):005:2>     members = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
irb(main):006:2>
irb(main):007:2*     for member in members do
irb(main):008:3*       if (id == member)
irb(main):009:4>         return true
irb(main):010:4>       end
irb(main):011:3>     end
irb(main):012:2>     return false
irb(main):013:2>   end
irb(main):014:1> end
=> :login
```

---

Your code could be more Ruby-like:

```
def login(id)
  ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'].each do |member|
    return true if (id == member)
  end
  return false
end
login('ghi') # => true
login('foo') # => false
```

which can be refactored to:

```
def login(id)
  ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'].any? { |member| (id == member) }
end
login('ghi') # => true
login('foo') # => false
```

then to:

```
def login(id)
  ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'].include?(id)
end
login('ghi') # => true
login('foo') # => false
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explain. I put wrong parenthesis. I should remove that. Let me delete and try again. Thank you for your help.